# R -- For every element in a list, how can I set the same maximum value in each of j columns?

Tags: r, list, dictionary, lapply

In R, I have a list of i data frames. For j columns in each data frame, I want to recode values greater than 100 to 100. I can do this in a loop but am at a loss for how to do this using one of the apply functions.

Mock data and the loop:

```
a <- data.frame(letters[11:20],floor(runif(10, min = 10, max = 200)),floor(runif(10, min = 10, max = 200)),letters[1:10])
b <- data.frame(letters[11:20],floor(runif(10, min = 10, max = 200)),floor(runif(10, min = 10, max = 200)),letters[15:24])
d <- list(a,b)

for(i in 1:2){
    for(j in 2:3) {
    d[[i]][j] <- ifelse(d[[i]][,j] > 100, 100, d[[i]][,j])
    d}
}
```

What I've tried doing to get this to work using lapply (and Map).

1. The following works but will be a pain as I need to recode many more than two columns.

   ```
   e <- lapply(d, function(x) {
     x[,2] <- ifelse(x[,2] > 100, 100, x[,2])
     x[,3] <- ifelse(x[,3] > 100, 100, x[,3])
     x})
   ```
2. I tried following the advice given here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html

   ```
   j <- 2:3
   e <- Map(function(x,y) {
       x[,y] <- ifelse(x[,y] > 100, 100, x[,y])
       x},d,j)
   ```

This isn't quite right, as col 3 in d[[1]] has not been modified. Same with col 2 in d[[2]]

3. Next attempt:

   ```
   i <- 1:2
   j <- 2:3
   e <- Map(function(x,y,z) {
       x[[y]][,z] <- ifelse(x[[y]][,z] > 100, 100, x[[y]][,z])
       x},d,i,j)
   ```

Error in `[.default`(x[[y]], , z) : incorrect number of dimensions

I don't understand why I'm getting an incorrect number of dimensions error here. I'm clearly missing something, but it seems to me that:

```
x[[y]][,z] <- ifelse(x[[y]][,z] > 100, 100, x[[y]][,z])
```

is the same as:

```
x[,y] <- ifelse(x[,y] > 100, 100, x[,y])
```

from my earlier code block, which did not generate an error.

I imagine my problem stems from an incomplete understanding of the apply family of functions.

Help of any sort would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you want

```
lapply(d, function(x){x[2:3][x[2:3]>100] <-100;x})
```